# Python 実践データ分析100本ノック　ノック72に関して

Tags: python

下記のコードを実行すると `t` の値を変えてもノードが赤くなりません。間違い等あればご指摘頂きたいです。

環境はJupyter Notebookでnetworkxのバージョンは2.6.3まで入ってます。

```
import pandas as pd 
df_links =　pd.read_csv（"links.csv''）
df_links
```

```
import pandas as pd
df_links = pd.read_csv("links.csv")
df_links

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

NUM = len(df_links.index)
for i in range(1,NUM+1):
    node_no = df_links.columns[i].strip("Node")
    G.add_node(str(node_no))

for i in range(NUM):
    for j in range(NUM):
        node_name=  "Node"+str(j)
        if df_links[node_name].iloc[i]==1:
            G.add_edge(str(i),str(j))

nx.draw_networkx(G,node_color="k", edge_color="k", font_color="w")

plt.show()
```

```
import numpy as np

def determine_link(percent):
    rand_val = np.random.rand()
    if rand_val<=percent:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
def simulate_percolation(num, list_active, percent_percolation):
    for i in range(num):
        if list_active[i]==1:
            for j in range(num):
                 node_name=  "Node" + str(j)
            if df_links[node_name].iloc[i]==1:
                    if determine_link(percent_percolation)==1:
                        list_active[j] = 1
    
    return list_active

percent_percolation = 0.1
T_NUM = 36
NUM = len(df_links.index)
list_active= np.zeros(NUM)
list_active[0]=1
list_timeSeries= []

for t in range(T_NUM):
    list_active= simulate_percolation(NUM,list_active,percent_percolation)
    list_timeSeries.append(list_active.copy())
                    
def active_node_coloring(list_active):
    list_color = []
    for i in range(len(list_timeSeries[t])):
        if list_timeSeries[t][i]==1:
            list_color.append("r")
        else:
            list_color.append("k")
    
    return list_color

t= 0

nx.draw_networkx(G,font_color="w",node_color=active_node_coloring(list_timeSeries[t]))

plt.show()

t= 11

nx.draw_networkx(G,font_color="w",node_color=active_node_coloring(list_timeSeries[t]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: 一つ前のノック71の内容も必要らしいので、それも追記してみてください。あと配布されているソースコードからすると最後の3行くらいが不足しているようですが。

Comment: import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

NUM = len(df_links.index)
for i in range(1,NUM+1):
    node_no = df_links.columns[i].strip("Node")
    G.add_node(str(node_no))

for i in range(NUM):
    for j in range(NUM):
        node_name=  "Node"+str(j)
        if df_links[node_name].iloc[i]==1:
            G.add_edge(str(i),str(j))

nx.draw_networkx(G,node_color="k", edge_color="k", font_color="w")

plt.show()

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。71のほう追記しました。こちらは問題なく動きます　最後の3行ですが、Tの値を変更した場合のコードですので割愛しました。本によるとT = 11の場合に既に赤いノードが増えるはずなのですが、今回は増えていません。

Comment: ソースコードはコメントではなく質問記事本体に追記しましょう。(1つ前のノック内容なので先頭に挿入)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。先頭に插入しました。確認のほどよろしくお願いします。こちらの不手際で申し訳ありません。

Comment: `links.csv`ファイルを読んで`df_links`というDataFrameを作る部分が追記されていませんね。(警告を非表示にする部分も追記されていませんがそれは影響無いでしょう) それ(`df_links`というDataFrame)が無いと動かないはずですし、現在提示されている部分に配布されているソースコードの該当部分との違いが無いので、`df_links`というDataFrameの作り方が違うか作ってから何か書き変えたかあるいは`links.csv`ファイルの内容が書籍(あるいは配布内容)と合っていないといった事が考えられます。ちなみに配布されているソースコードやデータファイルをjupyterではなく素のPythonで使えるように変換して、Windows10,64bit Python 3.10.2,pandas 1.4.0,matplotlib 3.5.1,numpy 1.22.1,networkx 2.6.3 で`t`の値で赤いノード数が変わるように動作しています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。念のため追記しましたが、df_linksのDataflameは既に追加しており、特に結果に変化はありません。誤解を招いてしまい申し訳ありません。

Comment: csvの内容はソースコードとの違いはありませんでした。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。インデントを修正したところ、本の内容を再現することができました。

Comment: 何度も丁寧に対応して頂き本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

間違い部分が判明しました。
使っているツールのモードを間違えてPythonでは重要なインデントの違いが見つけられなくなっていました。
以下の関数の途中のインデントが違っています。

質問のソースで誤りの部分

```
def simulate_percolation(num, list_active, percent_percolation):
    for i in range(num):
        if list_active[i]==1:
            for j in range(num):
                 node_name=  "Node" + str(j)
            if df_links[node_name].iloc[i]==1: #### この行のインデントがずれて少なくなっていた
                    if determine_link(percent_percolation)==1:
                        list_active[j] = 1
    
    return list_active
```

正しい内容

```
def simulate_percolation(num, list_active, percent_percolation):
    for i in range(num):
        if list_active[i]==1:
            for j in range(num):
                node_name = "Node" + str(j)
                if df_links[node_name].iloc[i]==1:
                    if determine_link(percent_percolation)==1:
                        list_active[j] = 1
    return list_active
```